# Get logged on user's SMTP address via EWS?

Tags: exchangewebservices

I have a client app written using EWS Managed API 1.1. Here's the situation:

- The client does *not* run on a computer within the same domain as the Exchange Server.
- I have the username and password of a user, but not their email address.
- There's no commonality between username (e.g. ABC123\001234) and email address (e.g. joe.bloggs@company.com).

I can connect to EWS just fine, send messages, etc.

However my software needs to discover the authenticated user's email address, and for various requirements reasons can't just ask the user to provide it.

I assumed I'd be able to get such a simple detail back from the web service, but I'm stumped!

Is this possible for both 2007 and 2010?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to do it using [`ExchangeService.ResolveName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.resolvename%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx).  I tried it with the following EWS Managed API code example on Exchange 2007 and it worked like a charm:

```
var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
service.Url = new Uri("https://serv/EWS/exchange.asmx");
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("001234", "PasswordForUser001234", "Domain");

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) =>
    {
        return true;
    };

var resolvedNames = service.ResolveName("001234");
foreach (var resolvedName in resolvedNames)
{
    Console.WriteLine(resolvedName.Mailbox.Address);
}
```